# How can I programmatically visit a website without using curl?

Tags: bash, curl

I'm trying to send a large number of queries to my server.  When I open a certain website (with certain parameters), it sends a query to my server, and computation is done on my server.

Right now I'm opening the website repeatedly using curl, but when I do that, the website contents are downloaded to my computer, which takes a long time and is not necessary.  I was wondering how I could either open the website without using curl, or use curl without actually downloading the webpage.

Comment: Depends what you're trying to test. Are you stress testing the web server?

Comment: @n0pe I'm not really testing the server right now, I'm just using the server to compute things (and the answers to the computation are stored in the server logs, which I then download after I run all the queries).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the requests in parallel, like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

url="http://your.server.com/path/to/page"

for i in {1..1000} ; do
    # Start curl in background, throw away results
    curl -s "$url" > /dev/null &

    # Probably sleep a bit (randomize if you want)
    sleep 0.1 # Yes, GNU sleep can sleep less than a second!
done

# Wait for background workers to finish
wait
```

`curl` still downloads the contents to your computer, but basically a test where the client does not downloads the content would not be very realistic.

Obviously the above solution is limited by the network bandwith of the test server - which is, usually worse than the bandwith of the web server. For realistic bandwith tests you would need to use multiple test servers.

However, especially when it comes to dynamic web pages not the bandwith might be the bottleneck, but the memory or CPU. For such stress tests, a single test machine might be enough.

Comment: Thanks, that's a great idea!  Is this literally going to hit my server with 1000 queries at once?  I'm not sure how many queries it can handle (maybe fifty per second?)

Comment: I'm also not sure what happens if I send more queries to my server than it can handle

Comment: Do it and you'll see :) That's the purpose of the test ;)

Comment: The sleep 0.1 will cause it to send a request to your server every .1 seconds. So you will not receive 1000 requests at once. you will receive 10 requests per second.

Comment: You could change the `sleep 0.1` to `sleep 0.01` in order to receive 100 requests per second....Of course that is if your network and system can actually keep up with that.

Comment: Also Jessica, if you send more traffic to your server than it can handle, that is a perfect example of a DoS attack.